# Using least squares for computing gradients

Tags: least-squares

I am developing a code where I am using the least squares method to compute gradients.

Generally, we use least squares to obtain some model based on a set of data (${q_1 \cdots q_N}$) at locations (${x_1 \cdots x_N}$), and use this model to predict $q_c$ at $x_c$.

In my case, I am looking for $\nabla{q}$ at $x_c$ using least squares. Should the $q$ value at $x_c$ be included in a least squares model for its gradient at the location, or only the neighboring values?

I would like use the weighted least squares method. It seems the weighting matrix is defined as a diagonal matrix with the inverse of the variance squared along the main diagonal. The popular choice for the variance seems to be the distance between the neighboring data point and the point in question. So if I include the $q_c$ value at $x_c$ in my least squares model, then the variance would be zero for this data point, which would be problematic unless I add some $\epsilon$ value to the variance before taking it's inverse.

The least squares equation is

\begin{align}
\nabla q = q^TZM^T\nabla\phi(x) \\
\\
M=(Z^TZ)^{-1}\\
\\
\phi = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y & z & xy & xz & yz & 0.5x^2 & 0.5y^2 & 0.5z^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
Z_{unweight} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & x_1y_1 & x_1z_1 & y_1z_1 & 0.5x_1^2 & 0.5y_1^2 & 0.5z_1^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_N & y_N & z_N & x_Ny_N & x_Nz_N & y_Nz_N & 0.5x_N^2 & 0.5y_N^2 & 0.5z_N^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
q = \begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & \cdots & q_N
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$q_c$ is known, but I am not sure if this should be included in the above model.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're finding the gradient of $y(x_{c))$ with respect to what independent variables?

Comment: Yes, I am finding the gradient of y at $x_c$. The independent variable are the x's, which represents spatial coordinates in my case.

Comment: So you want the gradient of $y(x_{c})$ with respect to $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$, keeping $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$, $\ldots$, $y_{n}$ constant?  What's the equation that relates $y(x_{c})$ to $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$?

Comment: That is correct, I will update the original post, with the least squares equation.

Comment: Updated it. Note that I changed 'y' to 'q' because I am using 'y' to represent a spatial coordinate in the above eqn.

Comment: I use similar techniques a lot for calculating gradients of a function on a spatial grid, with SVD solving the linear system, it works fine. I would not omit the central grid point, otherwise the calculation may easily produce "red-black" type grid instabilities

Comment: @MaximUmansky I see. Do you use least squares for computing the gradients?

Comment: Yes, I have used this method a lot. For example, on a square 2D grid, using function values at the four vertices of a grid cell to calculate bilinear approximation to the function within the cell f =ax+by+c. Using SVD to solve the over-determined linear system with three unknowns and four given values. Maybe it is not exactly the same as the least square fit but something very similar.

Comment: Ahh. Have you encountered problems where it is underdetermined (given < unknowns)?

Comment: That sounds like fitting a bi-quadratic function to four vertices of a grid cell, or something like that. Probably that would not work well since there is not enough information to solve for the coefficients.

Comment: this question needs to be more clearly formulated. is "bold" x a vector? *say so in the quesiton* . Is `x` 3 d?? *say so* ..

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the following question. Given $(q_0,q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_N)$ find $\nabla q$ at $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_0$. You can do this two ways.

I. Assume

$$
q(x,y,z) = a + \vec{b} \cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)
$$
and find $a$ and $\vec{b}$ by 
$$
\min_{a,\vec{b}}\sum_{i=0}^N(q(x_i,y_i,z_i) - q_i)^2
$$

II. Assume

$$
q(x,y,z) = q_0 + \vec{b} \cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)
$$
and find $\vec{b}$ by 
$$
\min_{\vec{b}}\sum_{i=1}^N(q(x_i,y_i,z_i) - q_i)^2
$$

In either case, $\vec{b}$ will give an approximation to $\nabla q$ at $\vec{r}_0$.

In (II), you have $q(x_0,y_0,z_0)=q_0$ but in (I) you only have $q(x_0,y_0,z_0) \approx q_0$.

If you want to put in weights based on some inverse distance in above norm, then even in (I) you are forcing $q(x_0,y_0,z_0)=q_0$ to hold. In this case, you can just use approach (II) after putting in the weights appropriately in the norm.